# I installed Ubuntu on an USB flash drive but it resets after every reboot

Tags: boot, usb-drive, reset

I recently installed Ubuntu on an USB flash drive to get some experience with it and also have a portable OS with my personal files. I used [this](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview) Tutorial but when I reboot the system it resets back to how it was after the fresh installation. Do I need to use a different method to install Ubuntu on the flash drive or did I do something wrong?

Comment: You made a bootable system that is supposed to reset each time nothing gets saved to it.

Comment: You want to follow this instead. https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/03/create-persistent-storage-live-usb-with.html#:~:text=To%20create%20a%20persistent%20storage%20live%20USB%2C%20click%20on%20the,Ubuntu%20%2D%2C%20and%20click%20OK%20.&text=Select%20the%20Ubuntu%20(including%20Kubuntu,and%20click%20OK%20to%20continue.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1320327/running-ubuntu-from-external-ssd-hdd-without-reset-upon-reboot/1320402#1320402 For comparison between Persistent and Full install to USB.

Comment: @user68186 et al: There are 23 active answers on that page, Most are very long and many are obsolete, (the app in the answer with most votes was abandoned in 2015). Another answer instructs the User to demo Ubuntu running off CD/DVD. Even if the user could find a CD/DVD the slowness of the experience would be bound to scare them off. **Which answer would you suggest the OP start with?**