# Running Ubuntu from external SSD / HDD without reset upon reboot

Tags: boot, usb, hard-drive, ssd

I have just created a Live Ubuntu USB (using a SanDisk Cruiser Blade 64GB, USB 2.0) thinking I would have a portable "computer" I could plug into any machine and continue with my work. I read about [creating a persistent bootable Ubuntu usb](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/) which sounded almost like the thing I wanted but it has limitations which I don't want when using Ubuntu. I would dual boot my own machine at best but I lack the storage and need my windows system.

I was hoping to find someone who can tell me if the same limitations would occur on an external SSD / HDD as I still really like the idea of having a device I can plug into any computer and boot into Ubuntu with all my data saved on it.

Comment: If you do a real, full installation to your USB drive then you will have a full, real Ubuntu installation without the limits you'd have with a USB drive setup for persistence. If you do decide to do this, be careful about where GRUB gets installed. Many folks simply disable their internal drive(s) prior to installing, just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

### Full Install vs Persistent install

**Comparison between Persistent and Full install USB**

**Advantages of a persistent install:**

1. You can use the persistent pendrive to install Ubuntu to another computer.
2. A persistent install takes up less space on the pendrive.
3. You can reset the pendrive by overwriting the old casper-rw file with a new one.
4. The install to pendrive takes less time.
5. Slightly less wear on the drive.

**Advantages of a Full install:**

1. You can update and upgrade.
2. If you have problems or wish to modify, the solution is the same as with an internal install, (You can ask for help in the forums).
3. No ugly startup / install screen.
4. Better security, you can use full encryption
5. You can use proprietary drivers.
6. Hibernation can be activated.
7. Many persistent installs are limited to a 4GB casper-rw and a 4GB home-rw persistence file, to get more persistence requires persistence partitions. Once casper-rw is full, the drive will not boot.
8. More efficient usage of disk space. Does not require reserved space for persistence.
9. Faster boot, **no automatic disk checking** or Try Ubuntu/Install Ubuntu screen.
10. You can run VBox and use virtual machines.
11. Generally faster boot than Live or Persistent USB's.
12. More stable

Note that once booted, both methods run at about the same speed. If the computer has lots of RAM Ubuntu should run mainly in RAM and there will not be a big difference between running off internal HDD and USB3 flash drive.

**Full Install Method**

A quick and easy method to flash a Full install to USB can be found here: [Easy Full Install USB that Boots both BIOS and UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300454/easy-full-install-usb-that-boots-both-bios-and-uefi)

A more traditional methods for creating a Full install USB from scratch can be found here: [How to Create a Full Install of Ubuntu 20.04 to USB Device Step by Step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-st)